# How to make TagsInput to work with both auto complete & free text

Tags: twitter-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

**UPDATE**
This issue is already discussed in github [here](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/487)

I am using tagsinput with typeahead in bootstrap 3. The problem which I am experiencing is with the value in case if user selects the existing tag. Display text shows it right but .val() returns its actual object. Below is the code

```
 $('#tags').tagsinput({
                        //itemValue: 'value',
                        typeahead: {
                            source: function (query) {
                                //tags = [];
                                //map = {};
                                return $.getJSON('VirtualRoomService.asmx/GetTags?pid=' + $("#<%=hdnPID.ClientID%>").val() + '&tok=' + query)
                                //, function (data) {
                                //    $.each(data, function (i, tag) {
                                //        map[tag.TagValue] = tag;
                                //        tags.push(tag.TagValue);
                                //    });
                                //    return process(tags);
                                //});
                            }
                        }
                        //freeElementSelector: "#freeTexts"
                    });
```

The problem with above code is that it results as below while fetching tags from web method
[image]

This happens when user select the existing tag. New tags no issues. I tried setting itemValue & itemText of tagsinput but not worked. Hence I decided a work-around of this problem. Since I could able get the json string as ['IRDAI", Object], if can somehow parse these object & get the actual tag value then I get the expected result of the code I am looking at.

Below is what it appears in tags input as [object Object] for text selected by user from auto populated drop down
[![enter imt
If I i specify TagId & TagValue to itemValue & itemText as below code

```
            $('#tags').tagsinput({
                itemValue: 'TagId',
                itemText: 'TagValue',
                typeahead: {
                    source: function (query) {
                        //tags = [];
                        //map = {};
                        return $.getJSON('VirtualRoomService.asmx/GetTags?pid=' + $("#<%=hdnPID.ClientID%>").val() + '&tok=' + query)
                        //, function (data) {
                        //    $.each(data, function (i, tag) {
                        //        //map[tag.TagValue] = tag;
                        //        tags.push(tag.TagValue);
                        //    });
                        //});
                        //  return process(tags);

                    }
                }
                //freeElementSelector: "#freeTexts"
            });
```

Then the result is displaying as below when below code is executed

```
var arr = junit.Tags.split(',');

                            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                                $('#tags').tagsinput('add', arr[i]);
                            }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly does `VirtualRoomService.asmx/GetTags` return when presented with a token that matches existing tags?

Comment: it returns its id and value

Comment: Ok, but what does it look like? Can you provide an example? Like `[{"value":12, "text":"Sweet Tag"},...]` ?

Comment: The result data from GetTags will be like [{"TagId":"1", "TagValue":"eSign"},{"TagId":"2", "TagValue":"eInsurance Account"}]

Comment: updated the question with a new screen shot. Please refer to the question

Answer (score 1):

Given your example JSON response from your data source:

```
[
  {"TagId":"1", "TagValue":"eSign"},
  {"TagId":"2", "TagValue":"eInsurance Account"}
]
```

You'll need to tell tagsinput how to map the attributes from your response objects using `itemValue` and `itemText` in your tagsinput config object. It looks like you may have started down that path, but didn't reach the conclusion, which should look something like:

```
$('#tags').tagsinput({
  itemValue: 'TagId',
  itemText: 'TagValue',
  typeahead: {
    source: function (query) {
      return $.getJSON('VirtualRoomService.asmx/GetTags?pid=' + $("#<%=hdnPID.ClientID%>").val() + '&tok=' + query);
    }
  }
});
```

Be sure to checkout the [tagsinput examples](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/tree/master/examples/assets).

Comment: This did not work for me, please refer to my question updated with new screen shot

Comment: I did even try changing the code to $('#tags').tagsinput('add', {TagId:1, TagValue: arr[i]}) still the issue remain same. Refer to the screenshot in my question

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the clean solution but I got around this issue through below parsing method. Hope this helps someone.

```
            var items = $('#tags').tagsinput("items");
            var tags = '';
            for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            {
                if(JSON.stringify(items[i]).indexOf('{') >= 0) {
                    tags += items[i].TagValue;
                    tags += ',';
                } else {
                  tags += items[i];
                  tags += ',';
                }
            }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do this for, but "cleaner" might look more like `var tagArr = []; ... if(typeof items[i] == 'object') { tagArr.push(items[i].TagValue) } else { tagArr.push(items[i]) } var tags = tagsArr.join(',')` But, then again, I'm now really confused as to what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is much cleaner.